# PySpark - parallel processing

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I belive it is a bacis question about data processing in spark.
Let's assue, there is a data frame:

| PartitionColumn | ColumnB | ColumnC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | value1 |  |
| First | value2 |  |
| Second | row |  |
| ... | ... | ... |

I am going to processig this data pararell using the `PartitionColumn`, so all rows with *First* value go to the *First* table, with the *Second* values go to the *Second* table etc.
Could I ask for a tip how to achive it in PySpark (2.x)?

Comment: see [`.repartition()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.repartition.html#pyspark-sql-dataframe-repartition) where you can pass the partition column name as well.

Comment: Thanks, what next? How can I export data to destination parallel? Should I use any python component that supports parallel processing (sending to dest table) or this functionality is bult-in in pyspark?

Comment: spark operations are already parallelized.

Comment: Does it make sense to apply `foreachPartition()`? Would it export data faster to destination Hive table? https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-foreachpartition-vs-foreach-explained/

Comment: i'd steer away from it in this use case. you could just create a partitioned hive table from spark as you can easily run sql queries -- see `spark.sql()`

Answer (score 0):

Please refer **partitionBy()** section in [this documentation](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-partitioning-understanding/)

```py
df.write \
  .partitionBy("PartitionColumn") \
  .mode("overwrite") \
  .parquet("/path")
```

Your partitioned data will be saved under folders:

- /path/First
- /path/Second

Comment: @skolukmar, did this solution work for you?